# Arrays map function javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

In the below code I am trying to pass the value of realdata[0] = 700 & realdata[1]=300 to the draw method.

> return {label:d.label, value:realdata[i], color:d.color}; ++i;

However the logic would not work ? Can someone guide me i am new to javascript.

```
var salesData=[
    {label:"Used", color:"#FF3300"},
    {label:"Free", color:"#00FF00"}
];

Donut3D.draw("salesDonut", randomData(), 150, 150, 150, 120, 30, 0.3);


function randomData(){

    var realdata = [700,300];
    var i=0;

return salesData.map( function(d){  

        return {label:d.label, value:realdata[i], color:d.color}; ++i; 

         } );

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at underscore.js

Comment: Placing `++i;` after the `return` statement makes it unreachable code.

Comment: jslint (or any other javascript linter) may help you with some of these problems. I suggest using an editor that has it built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `++i` isn't able to execute being after a `return` statement, which stops and exits the `function`. So, the value of `i` isn't changing between iterations of `map`.

To resolve this, you can use a suffix increment, `i++` (*increment, but return the former value*), within the `return` statement:

```
return { label: d.label, value: readdata[i++], color: d.color };
```

Or, [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will provide an index value as the 2nd argument for the iterator:

```
function randomData(){
    var realdata = [700,300];

    return salesData.map(function (d, i) {
        return { label: d.label, value: readdata[i], color: d.color };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have place the increment logic after a return statement which means `i` will never be incremented.  You could change your logic to:

```
 // post increment i inline
 return {label:d.label, value:realdata[i++], color:d.color};
```

However, `Array.map` will pass the current value, the index of the current value and the original array.

See: [MDN - Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Rather than keeping track of the index separately, changing your randomData function to:

```
function randomData(){
    var realdata = [700,300];

    return salesData.map( function(d, idx){  
        return {label:d.label, value:realdata[idx], color:d.color}; 
    });
}
```

Will result in:

```
[{"label":"Used","value":700,"color":"#FF3300"},    
 {"label":"Free","value":300,"color":"#00FF00"}]
```